# Unable to decode json variable using json_decode

Tags: php, json

I am using PHP with `json_decode` to convert.

Tried with `json_decode` its not converting and checked json format if any thing is wrong unfortunately i cant notice any thing in my json.

Someone Please tell me what is wrong.

```
$rawData='{"userName":"GBAB2C","action":"PaymentTransaction","mode":"TEST","reSellerId":"","postData":"{"ticketTypes":[{"index":0,"id":38,"fromResellerId":null,"quantity":20,"sellingPrice":null,"redeemStart":"2017-07-19 00:00:00","redeemEnd":null},{"index":1,"id":683,"fromResellerId":null,"quantity":20,"sellingPrice":null,"redeemStart":"2017-07-1900:00:00","redeemEnd":null}],"customerName":"elavarasan","email":"elavarasan@dss.com.sg","paymentMethod":"CREDIT","isInstantRedeemAll":false}","currencyCode":"INR","totalAmount":10,"referenceId":0,"hashKey":"cbe5eb31c43a134adb5835385a363eb2""apiFunctionName":"process","access":"mobile"}';
```

Used below line to convert

```
$_Ainput  = (array)json_decode($rawData, true);
```

Comment: The JSON is invalid, looks as though the value of `postData` should be encoded (maybe as JSON but has slashes striped out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple error in your json string.

1. There should be comma before json key ("apiFunctionName").
2. if you are creating nested json like for postData the value sound not be in ""(double quotes). it should be like "postData":{"ticketTypes":[{....},

This should like below..

```
$rawData='{
"userName":"GBAB2C",
"action":"PaymentTransaction",
"mode":"TEST",
"reSellerId":"",
"postData":{"ticketTypes":[{"index":0,"id":38,"fromResellerId":null,"quantity":20,"sellingPrice":null,"redeemStart":"2017-07-19 00:00:00","redeemEnd":null},
            {"index":1,"id":683,"fromResellerId":null,"quantity":20,"sellingPrice":null,"redeemStart":"2017-07-1900:00:00","redeemEnd":null}
            ],
        "customerName":"elavarasan",
        "email":"elavarasan@dss.com.sg",
        "paymentMethod":"CREDIT",
        "isInstantRedeemAll":false
        },
"currencyCode":"INR",
"totalAmount":10,
"referenceId":0,
"hashKey":"cbe5eb31c43a134adb5835385a363eb2"
,"apiFunctionName":"process",
"access":"mobile"}';
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

What's the return? You have to make sure that the one you decoding is a valid JSON before you can decode it. Based on the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues

Comment: its returning empty, yes i checked JSON. Cant find what i missed to convert. Even tried online converter its returning empty. For Sure something wrong in JSON unable to find what i did mistake

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the format specified to `$rawData` variable is incorrect. The correct format in PHP is

```
$rawData=["userName" => "GBAB2C","action" => "PaymentTransaction"]; // Truncated the rest
$json_encoded_data = json_encode($rawData);
```

To decode

```
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_encoded_data, true); //Passing second argument as true will convert to array
print_r($decoded_data);
```